# How can I launch an external application from a Java GUI in Linux?

Tags: java, process, runtime, desktop

I'm creating a Java application that helps people to learn Chinese. I've already created a Java GUI but I'm struggling to work out how to create a button that launches an external application in a new window.

I've looked up various tutorials on process, desktop and runtime but they all seem to deal with outputting data on the console, and I can't figure out how to apply them to this case.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT

So I've incorporated the runtime code into my class and I've got it to list the contents of my file but can't get it to launch the application using "/home/kate/Desktop/PTAMM ./PTAMM" or "./PTAMM /home/kate/Desktop/PTAMM" or "./ home/kate/Desktop/PTAMM PTAMM" (I tried the last two out of desperation). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here you go

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command to launch executable");
```

**See**

- [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Comment: @Kate, the above is what you need, you just have to replace the String with what you normally used to launch that external app from the command line/console

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I run the application by using ./PTAMM. So would this command work?: home/kate/Desktop/PTAMM ./PTAMM? I would try it now but I'm not at the stage where I'm able to do so yet.

Comment: For better understanding of Runtime.exec() read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked up various tutorials on process, desktop and runtime but they all seem to deal with outputting data on the console,

No that is wrong!  [Desktop.open(File)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) ..

> Launches the **associated** application to open the file.

(Emphasis mine)

So `Desktop.open(new File("word.doc"))` might open MS Word or the Open Office Writer, while `Desktop.open(new File("spreadsheet.xls"))` might pop MS Excel of OO Calc.

To play with the `Desktop` class, try the code on the [File Browser GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui) thread.

---

If you decide to go with using `Runtime`.  I suggest:

- Read & implement **all** the advice shown in [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).
- Use `ProcessBuilder` to construct the `Process`.  `ProcessBuilder` even has a convenience method to merge the output streams, to make them easier to 'consume'.

You might conclude after reading that article that using`Desktop` is the simpler option.  There are many traps & pitfalls involved with using a `Process`.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I looked up Desktop.open but all I can see that it does is open a file, which I don't want to do, I want to launch an application. Believe me I'd LOVE to use the easier option but I think Runtime is better suited to this.

Comment: How exactly does opening a program (with no source document), help people to learn Chinese?  What specific program(s) are of interest, and why?

Comment: It's an augmented reality program called PTAMM that I'm using to superimpose Chinese words on top of real life objects.